# How to redirect if date.php?date=* not found or doesn't exist

Tags: php, html, mysql, redirect, mysqli

can someone tell me how to redirect to another page if ".php?date=" doesn't found.
p.s i have distinct it and i think that is problem, so how to solve it? 
thanks before hand

```
<!--====================
```

left-block.php 
    ======================-->

```
<ul class="side-block">
                <li><a href="#">არქივი</a></li>
                <?php 
             $archive = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT DISTINCT left(date,7) as month FROM blog ORDER BY month DESC , id DESC LIMIT 6");
             while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($archive)){
                 printf('<li><a href="date.php?date=%s" class="custom">%s</a></li>',$myrow["month"],$myrow["month"]);
                }
?>
            </ul>
<!--
===============================================
date.php
===============================================
-->

<?php 
     include 'bd/blocks/bd.php'; 
     $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT keywords,description,author FROM page WHERE page='blog'");
     $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($_GET['date']) && !empty($_GET['date'])){
    $date = $_GET['date'];
}
elseif (!isset($_GET['date']) && empty($_GET['date'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
$date= "$date";
$dates=substr($date,0,7);
$result2 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT date FROM blog WHERE date='$dates' ");
$myrow2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
echo mysqli_num_rows($result2);
if(!mysqli_num_rows($result2)){
 header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
     $date_title=$date;
     $date_begin =$date;
     $date++;
     $date_end=$date;
     $date_begin=$date_begin.'-00';
     $date_end=$date_end.'-00';
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to explain what isn't being found more clearly.  Is date.php itself what is missing?  Or if the `date` parameter is not set/provided by the client?

Comment: date parameter is not set/provided by the client

Answer (score 1):

You can't use headers to redirect after you've output anything to the page. Use something like this instead which echoes out javascript alternative:

```
else {
    echo("<script>location.href = 'www.myurlhere.com';</script>");
}
```

Comment: But here  $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id='$id'");
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(!mysqli_num_rows($result)){
 header("Location: index.php");
 exit;
} everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_GET["date"])){
header("Location: http://newsite");
}
$date=$_GET["date"];
?>
```

As macroman pointed out, this only works if its at the very top of the page, before the first  or echo.

Comment: not working if i write date.php?date=99999 that does not show anything instead of redirect

Comment: This is not a copy to paste code. Its an example to help you improve your code

Comment: Try removing the if(){}elseif(){}else{} with something simple like my answer. There must be the mistake in this part of code.